# Undefined method 'rake' for rake task with Rufus Scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rufus-scheduler

having some trouble setting up Rufus Schedular to perform a *rake* task. Using *Rufus-schedular* rather then *whenever* gem as on windows.

*/lib/tasks/api.rake*

```
require 'rake'
namespace :api do
  desc "TODO"
  task update: :environment do
  puts "hello world"
  end
end
```

*/config/schedule.rb*

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'rake'
require 'lib/tasks/api.rake'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '3s' do
 Rake::Task["api:update"].invoke
end

scheduler.join
```

Gives the following error: **NoMethodError 220 undefined method `rake' for main:Object**

Comment: I think you might be looking for `Rake::Task["api:update"].invoke`?

Comment: I then get 'uninitialized constant Rake'. do I need to require my api.rake file in my schedule.rb file?

Comment: Based on that error you will need to add `require 'rake'` at a minimum. You may also have to load the task file.

Comment: I've updated my code above to reflect your suggested changes - but now I'm getting a 'cannot load -- lib/tasks/api.rake (LoadError)'.

Comment: Sorry maybe my last comment was unclear you need to `load` the rake task not `require` it e.g. `load Rails.root.join('lib','tasks','api.rake')` or depending on your dependencies `Rails.application.load_tasks` will load all the rails rake tasks.

Comment: I recommend that in the future you include the exact error messages that you receive including the stacktrace, as well as the exact commands that you ran that triggered the errors. This back-and-forth conversation could have been mostly avoided with detailed error messages in your post.